# Manually create spring security authentication token without user and password

Tags: spring-security

My application gets a custom token on basis of which I have to login.
I have a custom application code to check if token is valid or not.

e.g

```
public class CustomAuthenticationTokenProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    // logic for validating the token. This gives a validated authentication

    ...
    ...

    //Here first argument to constructor is principal and 2nd argument is //credentials. 
    CustomAuthenticationToken customAuthenticationToken = new CustomAuthenticationToken(authentication.getToken(), null);
    return customAuthenticationToken;
}
}
```

I have test above and it works fine.

Query: Do I necessarily require credentials to create a successfull authentication object. Are there any risks involved in such approach.

Answer (score -1):

No, you actually can create an Authentication object fully authenticated without any credentials, but ask yourself... you are giving full authentication to a user without providing any credentials, so anybody who could reach your filter's processing url would be able to get authenticated.

You must be very carefull with this application token, as anybody who gets this will be able to access your protected url's

Comment: Yes true. But in this case, I am getting a request parameter which contains a key which I authenticate (using my custom code) and if only if this request parameter is of a valid user then only I will create successful authentication token.

Comment: Do you see any serious issue with this approach?